# Stamped on entry but not on exit, does Immigration think I am still in UK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, multiple-entry, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India but I stay in Spain. I have a 2-year Standard Visitor visa to UK. I can travel to UK six months in one year. Recently I went to London for the first time. While entering, Immigration checked my passport and stamped it. So my clock ticking started. But when returning back to Spain, **no one** in the airport checked my passport (except airline employees to issue boarding pass). When I landed in Spain, they saw only my Spanish resident card.

Is my clock still ticking (for UK visa) and the time is being counted?

Comment: Just adding...  "I can travel to UK 6 months in 1 year.", this is incorrect; to state the rule correctly, you can stay for 6 months on any one visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UK has an [electronic way of checking exit dates](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet) (which was introduced this year), taken from flight records. So most likely your visa stays will be calculated based on that. Since you have no paper record, you'll have to keep track of your visit lengths yourself to stay within the criteria.

Comment: It might be a very good idea to keep a list and documents like tickets.

Comment: @Geeky did you get a passport stamp when you entered Spain?  If so, you can use that as evidence that you left the UK no later than the date of the stamp.  Therefore, if their system somehow missed your exit (as the comparable system in the US often does), you will still be fine.

Comment: Hi, My passport is been stamped in Spain, but they did not scan my passport.