# U.K. Overstay and re entry

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

I have a problem. I overstayed my uk tourist visa for about 10 months and decided to return voluntarily. However during my exit in February 2016, I did not meet any immigration officer at the Heathrow Terminal 3 before boarding the plane. I just went through the normal boarding process everyone went through without getting my passport stamped as an overstayer. Now I have gained admission to study a master's program in September in the uk and would like to make an application for a visa at the uk embassy In my home country. Is there any likelihood that the visa officer might know I overstayed my first visa even though nothing shows in my passport? Any help please? Thank you. Note my passport was never expired so it's the same passport I came back with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stamped on entry but not on exit, does Immigration think I am still in UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57750/stamped-on-entry-but-not-on-exit-does-immigration-think-i-am-still-in-uk)

Comment: Now they have automated exit controls. They know.

Answer (score 11):

The UK does not directly inspect passports on exit, so it is no surprise that you have no passport stamp.  Instead, [since April 2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet), they have collected information from airline passenger manifests.  They therefore almost certainly know about your overstay, in which case if you fail to mention it in your application you will almost certainly be banned for deception.

Comment: Okk I understand phoog. I think I will just have to go with the truth and hope I get the visa based on merits. I have however served my one year ban on overstayers who live voluntarily and so I hope it doesn't affect my application. Thank you very much

Comment: @kenzy12 they don't ask you on the form if you overstayed previously.

Comment: @greatone they ask for your immigration history.

Comment: @phoog they ask a few questions about it but not specifically about any overstay.

Comment: @greatone are you recommending that the applicant not mention the overstay?

Comment: @phoog yes, he doesn't need to mention something that they haven't asked for. There ARE some forms that ask about overstaying but uk visa application forms are not amongst them. There is no deception in this case.

Comment: @greatone what about the deception employed when Kenzy12 entered the UK the last time? There are questions on the site from people who are having trouble because they stayed longer than they said they would when they entered, even though they left within six months of entry.  Really, things look very bad for Kenzy12, and failing to mention the overstay is almost certain to make them worse.

Comment: @phoog there is nothing to go by to say the OP used deception when he entered. And even if he used deception to enter he was not labeled as an illegal entrant to affect his status. Stop making it so difficult. On the other hand he will be required to enter the length of the last stay--which would lead to declaring the overstay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57257/discussion-between-phoog-and-greatone).

Comment: Thanks to everyone about your responses. I really appreciate it. I think I have to go with the truth to prevent further complications. Hopefully everything turns out well for me. Thanks to everyone on this platform. Bless